# How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements where same item can couple?

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

I have a list of 6 items, [a,b,c,d,e,f]
I want to make a list of all possible combinations where there will be 2 items in the combination and the same items can couple to make a combination, like **(a,a)**.

My final output should be something like:
(a,a)
(a,b)
(a,c)
(a,d)
....

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ['a','b','c','d']
result=[]
for i in list:
    for j in list:
        result.append((i,j))
print(result)
```